# Autocomplete with Token field in Angular 4

Tags: angular, autocomplete, bootstrap-tokenfield

can anyone please tell me how add a autocomplete with token field in angular 4.

I want something below like this.

http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a tutorial site; you should try a framework such as Angular Material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below links will helps to achieve

1. https://github.com/lw0110/quick-editor
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tag-input

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for Answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest checking out [`ngx-chips`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) or, if you're using Angular Material, [`md-chips`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips).